# Accessing Instance created in worker thread from main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have created a metronome android application which writes synthetic sound to an AudioTrack instance. When I ran it it locked up my app completely. I understand that problem and have got round this with creating the instance in its own thread.

i have been reading as much as i can about sending messages between threads, but i can not find any resources detailing how i could go about setting vars and calling methods (eg. start(), stop(), setBpm()) of the metronome instance from the main thread once it has been instantiated.

Im not particularly looking for a straight out fix all answer as i probably wouldnt understand it enough to implement it. if you could point me in the direction of some good reading / examples that would be better.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally you have a class implementing `Runnable` that is your thread. Keep a reference to that from your main thread and you can call methods in it.

When your main thread creates the `Runnable` it should pass in a reference to anything the `Runnable` needs to access - this can include a reference to the main object or any other object if desired.

So long as you properly `synchronize` the calls the two threads can then communicate with each other by making changes to the objects.

You should check out:

`ExecutorService`
`java.util.concurrent`
`synchronized`

That should give you a good set of tools to get started with.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Ill check all of that out.